# Throw Exception for custom twig function 'when it is not closed'

Tags: symfony, knockout.js, twig, syntax-highlighting

**How can I throw an exception for a Twig Extension (Function), when the *start* call is made but an *end* tag is missing?**

Story:

I followed [this guide](http://studgeek.com/2010/08/16/intellijidea-webstorm-knockout-data-bind-attributes/) to have syntax highlighting, js validation and also autocompletion in my knockout data-bind attributes for PHPStorm. Unfortunately, this doesn't work when I make use of script templates. Instead, it just shows the value of `data-bind` attributes as simple strings:

```
<script type="text/html" id="my-template">
  <div data-bind="
    text : someVar,
    css  : {
      'some-class' : myCondition,
      'some-other-class' : myOtherCondition
    }
  "></div>
</script>
```

So I wrote a little Twig extension to ease my work with PHPStorm and knockoutjs-templates.

The extension has two functions: one to open a `<script>` tag and one to close http://pastebin.com/3Qq0JnyB:

```
{{ script_start('my-id') }}
  <div data-bind="
    text : someVar,
    css  : {
      'some-class' : myCondition,
      'some-other-class' : myOtherCondition
    }
  "></div>    
{{ script_end() }}
```

which works very well. I have my highlighting back. Yay!

It would be much nicer when I could get a little slap from the code (by throwing an exception) when the `script_end` call isn't made in the current scope.